# how to store beautiful soup tag inner html as string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Not sure what I overlook but I have a relative simple problem.

I'm scraping a page that contains a couple of article tags that I call like this (simplified version) :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all("article", "product-tile promotion")

for a in articles:
   print(a)

# This nicely prints all of my article tags and it's inner html, so up to here all is ok

str = ''.join(articles)

# Here things obviously go wrong, as I am trying to converse a bs4 tag to a string, and that's not supported...

file_name = 'list.xml'
complete_name = os.path.join(user_path, file_name)
file_object = codecs.open(complete_name, "w", "utf-8")
file_object.write(str)
```

I can print articles and it shows me exactly what I need.
But then I get stuck when I want to write all these articles away to a single string, as I want to keep the full inner HTML opposed to the usual text only solutions found.

So my actual question is, how can I get my tags stored as they are (so not just the text but including all elements and attributes to be found) so I can save this away as an xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is good you want to print all your tag `articles`, but not just the text, in xml file right?

In that case you can try this, first you save the articles in a list then you print each element in a loop, with a str cast:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all("article", "product-tile promotion")

articles_list = []
for a in articles:
    articles_list.append(a)
    #print(a)

# This nicely prints all of my article tags and it's inner html, so up to here all is ok

#str = ''.join(articles)

# Here things obviously go wrong, as I am trying to converse a bs4 tag to a string, and that's not supported...

file_name = 'list.xml'
complete_name = os.path.join(user_path, file_name)
file_object = codecs.open(complete_name, "w", "utf-8")
for al in articles_list:
    file_object.write(str(al))
```

**EDIT:**
Or it is possible to simply use the first list:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all("article", "product-tile promotion")

file_name = 'list.xml'
complete_name = os.path.join(user_path, file_name)
file_object = codecs.open(complete_name, "w", "utf-8")
for a in articles:
    file_object.write(str(a))
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've tried something similar already but it gives a 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable' message now.

Comment: @Wokoman could you give the url, because I tested this snipped on a website, with `li` in place of `articles` and it worked

Comment: never mind, I just noticed I was so stupid to have a variable called str earlier in my process. It's ok now and when I quit banging my head over this I can proceed...

Comment: The first `for` loop is redundant here, you're just creating a new list of `bs4.element.Tag` elements.

Comment: @QHarr yes indeed

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns a list of `bs4.element.Tag` elements, not a list of strings. You can cast each element to a string.

Try replacing

```
for a in articles:
   print(a)
```

with

```
for i in range(len(articles)):
   articles[i] = str(articles[i])
   print(articles[i])
```